# HP Dl160 G6: How to reset NVRAM?

Tags: hp-proliant

- The DL160 G6 does not boot, does not do post, but instead just powers on fans at full speed. I reseated ram, procs, hard drives with no luck.
- I should mention that when I powered it on, installed ESXi, and shut it down so I could bring it to another location (traveling distance <2 min by foot)
- Once plugged in to the new location it powers on at full fan speed, no post, no video output, no usb power
- This looks like a recurring issue and the solution isn't too bad: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/DL360-G5-fans-running-at-full-speed-and-won-t-boot/td-p/4258310#.U8GZFPldUiU
- It says to reset the NVRAM. How do I actually reset the NVRAM?
- It says to move the jumper to another slot: A,B,C,D
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srzh6.jpg (Reference image for motherboard)
- However there is no jumper or plug plugged in
- Anyone with any experience or insight I would greatly appreciate it

Cheers :)

Comment: buy yourself a jumper its about $0.20

Comment: @ramhound Do you know where I can purchase one from? I have searched extensively and 'HP Jumper' is too vague of a search. Thanks!

Comment: I would contact HP. They likely have a part number for it.

Answer (score -1):

You're all kidding and yanking his chain, right?

Take a piece of metal and touch the two pins to short them out.

The only question I have is whether the machine needs to be powered on with the jumper in/pins shorted to clear NVRAM.